# Use a bash script to find a block of options within an XML file

Tags: xml, linux, bash, shell, sh

I have an XML file with the following structure:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<questions>
    <property name="q154">
        <q154>
            <Property name="intro" value="Based on the information, {{1}} is older than {{2}}"/>
            <Property name="op1">
                <Pstructure>
                    <Property name="choices">
                        <Value>Mary</Value>
                        <Value>John</Value>
                        <Value>Carl</Value>
                    </Property>
                    <Property name="correct-indices">
                        <Value>3</Value>
                    </Property>
                    <Property name="hints">
                        <Value>Some hint here</Value>
                        <Value>blah blach blah</Value>
                    </Property>
                </Pstructure>
            </Property>
            <Property name="op2">
                <Pstructure>
                    <Property name="choices">
                        <Value>Albert</Value>
                        <Value>Nicole</Value>
                        <Value>Lizeth</Value>
                    </Property>
                    <Property name="correct-indices">
                        <Value>1</Value>
                    </Property>
                    <Property name="hints">
                        <Value>Some hint here</Value>
                        <Value>blah blah blah</Value>
                    </Property>
                </Pstructure>
            </Property>
        </q154>
    </property>
    <property name="q155">
        <q155>
            </Property name="intro" value="You get the idea ......."/>
            </Property>
        </q155>
    </property>
</questions>
```

As you can see, there is an intro text, some variables to be replaced on-the-go ({{1}} and {{2}}), there are options, hints, etc...

What I am trying to do, is to create a bash script that looks through the entire file and if it finds a "variable" {{1}} or {{2}}, it will print the entire intro text along with the line number, and below this, the corresponding options available for every particular variable.

So, the output of the script will be like this:

```
user@debian: ~/projectx$ ./myscript.sh questions01.xml

::: Finding variables and options in questions01.xml...
96: Based on the information, {{1}} is older than {{2}}
97: ...op1
99: ....choices
100: ..... Mary
101: ..... John
102: ..... Carl
113: ...op2
115: ....choices
116: ..... Albert
117: ..... Nicole
118: ..... Lizeth
::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
190: The winner of the race was {{1}}
191: ...op1
193: ....choices
194: ..... Lewis Hammilton
195: ..... Valtteri Bottas
196: ..... Daniel Ricciardo
197: ..... Kimi Raikkonen
```

This is what I have so far:

```
for f in "$1"*.xml
    do
        echo ::: Finding variables and options in $f...
        vars=$(grep -nEo ".{0,30}{{[0-9]}}.{0,30}" $f | uniq)
        if [ -n "$vars" ]
        then
            echo "$vars"
        fi
done
```

Which is not much, but I am getting the list of variables, along with some context (30 characters on each side) and the line numbers.

How can I pass this list of variables to some function or method to get the rest of the missing info in order to have the output that I posted above?

PS: It doesn't have to be done with grep, any other way is fine, as long as it prints the same output.

**Edit 1:**
If I split the requirements into steps, it'll be like this:

1. find each variable {{1}} or {{2}} and get the line number where it is located
2. Print the entire "intro" text where the variable was found
3. after that line number, find the next occurrence of "op1" or "op2"... Depending on {{1}}  {{2}}...
4. After finding that "opX" occurrence, find the next "choices"
   Property
5. Now, within that "choices" block, find each <value> tag and
   print its content.
6. repeat the cycle...

Then, the output will be as mentioned above.

Comment: if I understand what you're trying to acheive, this would be difficult even with proper XML aware tools, possibly an XSLT processor solution. Read thru some of the answers here `xmlstarlet` and separately XSLT as your search terms and see what I mean. I think you would need to have 2-4 separate processes, each that develop a stage of your solution, and then you'd need to "glue" them together. A great learning exercise, but if you're doing this for work best to disucss with your boss how to acquire time/resources to move things forward. Good luck!

Comment: Also, if you're not married to XML data, consider redefining what tools you can use to store/retrieve/manipulate your data. (You could also use an XML aware SQL database.)This seem more like a webpage with an SQL database backend (IMHO!). Good luck.

Comment: thank you @shellter this is indeed for work, but it is to make things easier for myself.
I am trying to check the grammar when the "questions" and "options" are displayed, so the entire sentence makes sense, for example, if one of the options is plural and the preceding to-be-verb is singular, then I have to move the verb to the options so it is grammatically correct (e.g. "the winner was <the girls on white>" will be edited to "the <winners were the girls on white>)... So, this part of the question "winner was" has to be moved to the options "winners were..." & "winner was..."

Comment: Wow, that addition is a separate problem on its own. It seems you know some about XML and the trade-offs of features vs strict requirement but the Q/A I see here on S.O. that gets help from XML gurus, includes a coded attempt (XSLT or xmlstarlet) at solving the problem. (I only read XML Qs, and am not qualified to answer) . StackOverflow is based around the idea of "one coding problem" and "one cannonical answer". Your Q has too many parts. I recommend breaking it up into mutltiple Qs where each is a small self contained  Q. Include your best attempt to solve that problem and U will mov fwd

Comment: I am not trying to make the grammar check automatically. To summarize I just want to be able to pass a file name (XML) to one script (SH) and get the variables {{1}} along with the available options for each of them. so I can see if there are grammar errors and then decide if I open the XML file and edit it manually or just continue to some other file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a shell script (myscript.sh) with the following lines:

```
#!/bin/bash
cat -n $* | perl -ne '
print "::::::::::::::::::\n$_" if /<Property name="intro"/;
print if /"op\d"/../"correct-indices"/;
' | perl -ne '
next if /<Pstructure>/ || m{</Property>} || /"correct-indices">/;
s/"intro"\s+value="//;
s/"(op\d+)">/$1/;
s/<Property name=//;
s/"choices">/choices/;
s{<value>}{}i;
s{</value>}{}i;
s{"/>}{};
print;
' | perl -ne '
s/\s+(.+?\{\{\d\}\}.+)/$1/;
s/\s+(op\d)/...$1/;
s/\s+choices/....choices/;
s/^\s+(.+?)/.....$1/;
print;
' | perl -pe '
s/^(\.+?)(\d+)\t\s+/$2: $1/;
s/\t\s+/: /;
s/^\.+(\d+)(\.+?)/$1: $2/;'
```

Executing it `./myscript.sh questions01.xml` will result in

```
::::::::::::::::::
5: Based on the information, {{1}} is older than {{2}}
6: ...op1
8: ....choices
9: .....Mary
10: .....John
11: .....Carl
22: ...op2
24: ....choices
25: .....Albert
26: .....Nicole
28: .....Lizeth
```